# Can the last row be center using isotope or masonry?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry, jquery-isotope

[image]
I have a masonry grid, sometimes the last row has less than 4 items. I want the last row to be centered in the middle of my container. The number of items on the last row can change depending on the responsiveness of my page that's why I can not use CSS to identify the last row items.

If someone has a solution please help. 
[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/oaoLuh4f/

```js
$('.masonry').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.masonry-brick',
  isFitWidth: true,
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 400
  }
});
$('.masonry').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.masonry-brick',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
});


$.each($(".masonry-brick"), function() {
  var blockHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).css({
    "height": blockHeight
  });
});
$.each($('.masonry'), function() {
  var masonryWrapperWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
  $('.masonry').css({
    "width": masonryWrapperWidth,
  });
});
```

```css
.masonry {
  margin: auto;
}
.masonry-brick {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #262524;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.2/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="masonry-brick">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide us with your **[minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I want the last row to be centered in the middle of my container." In your posted example, what's your row, and what's your container? I assume you mean centered horizontally? Perhaps it would help if you provided an image of what's happening now, and an image of what you'd like it to look like instead.

Comment: @age I added my code https://jsfiddle.net/oaoLuh4f/  - for reminding me

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I added images to illustrate the issue, thank you for your help. the ".masonry" is my container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with Masonry. The reason is that masonry doesn't really work with "Rows"--it just tries to fit your blocks into free spaces. So while the specific width you used in your example makes it appear that there are two rows, if you change the width slightly you get this instead:

[image: No rows]

If you tried to "center" the final block, it would mean that you're not fitting the pieces into the smallest space possible.

[image: Centered]

This would often end up looking weird, and it would be going against the purpose of masonry. If you prefer evenly-distributed rows, rather than filling in gaps, you can probably use ordinary centered `inline:block;` elements instead.